# WebSphere v8.5 Support For Arabic encoding

Tags: java, web, websphere, character, jakarta-ee

I am Calling a soap service from my java web application from the response of the soap server they are sending a field with Arabic name(ANSI format) i have converted to UTF-8 and displaying my JSP page .Now the problem is it is displaying in  properly in Tomcat server while it is deployed to was IBM web-sphere v8.5 it is displaying as ???

Any one can help me

i have copying the page encoding mentioned in  my Jsp page Below

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Answer (score 1):

What value(s) are set in the `<WAS_installdir>/properties/encoding.properties` file? There are circumstances where the value set in the encoding.propoerties file can override the content type specified in the JSP. The encoding.properties file contains a list of language/character set pairs.

You can try changing the values from the default ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 for your applicable languages. WAS will need to be restarted for this change to be picked up and will affect all applications running on the server.